# Remove my application from user with Dropbox API v2

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, webhooks

I'm creating a Dropbox application which uses a webhook to get the file's updates.
When a user uses my app, I receive notification on my webhook URL. Perfect.

But if the user no longer wants to use my app, and removes the Dropbox link from my site... How can I remove my app from the Dropbox user's account to not receive calls anymore on my webhook URL?

Answer (score 0):

The user can unlink an app from their account via the "Apps linked" section of their account security page:

https://www.dropbox.com/account/security

This will stop webhook notifications for that user from being sent to the app.

There isn't a way for the app to do this programmatically though. The Dropbox API only provides a way to revoke access tokens, but not a way to completely unlink the app from the account. We'll consider this a feature request for that though.

Comment: Wondering if Greg has any update on this ... Thanks!

Comment: @lugolabs No, unfortunately I don't have any news on this feature request.

Comment: @Greg not sure if you work for dropbox, but you're getting my feedback anyway haha... it would save us all a lot of bandwidth if you there was a way to programmatically disable webhooks. In our application, when I delete the dropbox integration (from our end), I don't have a way to tell Dropbox to stop sending me webhooks. Cheers!

Comment: @SunilD. Thanks! Yes, I'm a Developer Advocate at Dropbox. I'll send this feedback along to the team.